# Set 'y' axis to scientific notation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want my y axis to be formatted in scientific notation.

I have tried the [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.html#module-matplotlib.pyplot), but it ignores my command.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


x = np.random.randint(1e4, size=200)
y = np.random.randint(1e4, size=200)

plt.ticklabel_format(axis='both', style='sci')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.scatter(x,y, color='b', s=5, marker=".")

plt.show()
```

My output just appears in none-scientific notation.

For example I expect the ylabel `1000` to be `1E03`.

This code is just an example.

I have a sub-plot where plot 1 and 3 are in scientific notation, but plot 2 is in non-scientific notation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should just add `scilimits=(4,4)` to your command

`plt.ticklabel_format(axis='both', style='sci', scilimits=(4,4))`

for example your code will become:

```
x = np.random.randint(1e4,size=200)
y = np.random.randint(1e4,size=200)
plt.ticklabel_format(axis='both', style='sci', scilimits=(4,4))
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.scatter(x,y, color='b', s=5, marker=".")
plt.show()
```

Comment: the key factor, which works with ax from subplots too, is to select the format BEFORE plotting.

Comment: This seems to produce labels like "35x10^4" rathern than "3.5x10^5". I would suggest setting `scilimits=(0,0)` which seems to resolve the issue. (That indicates scientific form should be used for all numerical values.)

Answer (score 7):

Passing

```py
plt.ticklabel_format(axis='both', style='sci', scilimits=(0,0))
```

worked for me.

(as @Meysam-Sadeghi suggested, but without plt.subplots())

Comment: it works with ax from subplots too, but it is KEY to select the format BEFORE plotting.