# How to use matplotlib log scale in a graphic with two y axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```py
# Criar figura e eixos
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()



# Configurar o primeiro eixo (temperatura) e todas as curvas em função desse eixo
ax1.set_xlabel('Tempo (s)')
ax1.set_ylabel('Temperaturas (ºC)')

ax1.plot(df["Tempo"], df["Temp. Forno"], color='tab:red', label='Forno')
ax1.plot(df["Tempo"], df["ViewPort"], color='tab:orange', label='ViewPort')
ax1.plot(df["Tempo"], df["Água Flange"], color='tab:olive', label='Água Flange')
ax1.plot(df["Tempo"], df["Flange Inox"], color='tab:purple', label='Flange Inox')
ax1.plot(df["Tempo"], df["Tampa"], color='tab:pink', label='Tampa')

ax1.tick_params(axis='y')



# Criar o segundo eixo (pressão)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.set_ylabel('Pressão (mBar)')
ax2.plot(df["Tempo"], df["PressaoAlta"], color='tab:blue')
ax2.tick_params(axis='y')

#Abaixo segue uma tentativa de tornar o segundo eixo uma escala logarítmica
ax2.set_yscale('log')
ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.LogLocator(subs=(1.0, 2.5, 5.0)))
ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter())



# Adicionar legenda
ax1.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.2, 1.1), loc='upper left')
ax2.legend(['Pressão'], bbox_to_anchor=(1.435, 0.75), loc='upper right')



# Exibir o gráfico
plt.savefig('grafico')
plt.show()
```

[image: My graphic]

As we can see in the graphic, the right column is 0.0001, for example, and I want this and the subs in base equal to 10, like 10^-4.
I want the code to show the ax2 in scientific notation in log scale on the graphic. What can I do?

Comment: So, is your question just about how to show the axes in scientific notation, or are you asking for more? It is not clear.

Comment: Sorry that I'm not so good to deal with english, but i'm trying haha. But yeah, that's it. I want it in scientific notation

Comment: I don't think so. Actually, I don't know how can I complement my code with this, and I want it only in one side of the graphic and they did it for both sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Set 'y' axis to scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57093572/set-y-axis-to-scientific-notation), you can set an axis to scientific notation using `ax2.ticklabel_format(axis="y", style="sci")`. In the answer, they used `"both"`, which sets both the x and y axes to scientific notation, but you only need to apply it to the y-axis.

Comment: Oh, that worked implementing `scilimits=(-3,-5)`. Thank u so much @jared